# How to write this regular expression of Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href='http://example.com/' />
  <title>Example website</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='demo'>
 <div>Fruite:Apple&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sport:Football&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Language:English</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to get these 3 results,as follow:

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(r'')
u'Apple'

>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(r'')
u'Football'

>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(r'')
u'English'
```

How to write the regular expression in `re()` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w+` should do it. Where `\w` is a word character and `+` is greedy quantifier.

```
In: response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(r'\w+')  
Out: ['Fruite', 'Apple', 'Sport', 'Football', 'Language', 'English']
```

You can preappend `:` to only get the words after the colon: `:(\w+)`

```
In: response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(r':(\w+)')
Out: ['Apple', 'Football', 'English']
```

If you want only specific words then you can simply list out your words with `|`(or separator):

```
In: response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(r'Apple|Football|English')
Out: ['Apple', 'Football', 'English']
```

Comment: if the words 'Apple', 'Football', 'English' are chinese,` <div id='demo'>
 <div>水果:苹果&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;运动:足球&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;语言:英语</div>
  </div>`  the code is utf-8, how to get them? and I edit my question,plese see it again,thanks!

Comment: the second example should ignore the encoding, but if you want to include unicode characters in your regex just use python's unicode strings, e.g.: `re(u'果|足球')`

Answer (score 3):

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="demo"]/div/text()').re(':(\w+)')
```